# After installing postgres there is no configuration file. Can I add one?

Tags: passwords, postgresql

I am trying to use postgres without user authentication and according to these directions https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83164/remove-password-requirement-for-user-postgres

I need a configuration file like

> pg_hba.conf
>   or
>   postgresql.conf

I did an entire search on my computer and cannot find either of these files but when using the psql command, it still asks for a password and when I put in the user password to login to my computer, it says "password authentication failed..." As supplemental info I uninstalled postgres using homebrew to start all over again but it's still giving me this password trouble. I just want to use postgres with or without a password failure. Am I able to manually create a this configuration files, or maybe they're called something else, or is there another way to get around this password hangup? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration files are created when you initialize a PostgreSQL instance by running `initdb`.  Homebrew runs `initdb` in post-install, and it looks like it's supposed to end up in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`.